# Why doesn't DOM element behave when setting visibility or display with SPFx/Typescript?

Tags: spfx-webparts, typescript

code snippets here produce/render expected data and alert box shows [object HTMLDivElement] the div will not hide; same is true using "visibility", "hidden"

```
       <p>
           <input id="readGroups" type="button" value="Read Groups using GRAPH"/> 
           <input id="readWorkOrderUsers" type="button" value="View Your Work Orders"/> 
           </p>
        </div>
      </div>          
      <div class="${styles.container}" id="groupTableContainer"></div>
      <div class="${styles.container}" id="workOrderTableContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>`;

this.domElement.querySelector('#readWorkOrderUsers')
               .addEventListener('click',() => {
                var groupContainer : Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#groupTableContainer');
                alert(groupContainer);
                groupContainer.setAttribute("display","none");
                //this._readWorkOrders();
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because `display` is not an attribute of the HTML element `groupTableContainer`.

Style is an attribute, therefor this should work:

```
groupContainer.setAttribute("style", "{display:none;}");
```